# How to use DATENAME in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server-2008, where-clause

Am using Sql Server 2008, I have a column named Date in my table, and I want to get the datas for the particular date.... I need to give this Date in my WHERE condition.

for example, if I want to get the records for the particular month in the given date, how can I use this Date in WHERE condition.

```
DATANAME(MONTH,'@Date')
```

if I give like this in my query I can get the month from the given DATE, the same way I tried by putting in WHERE condition like,

```
WHERE DATE=    DATANAME(MONTH,'@Date')
```

here it reports conversion error...how can I display the datas for a particular month, can anyone help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a month of data for a table you should check against an interval. The query is not able to use indexes on the date column if you are applying functions on the column.

Use something like this to get data for April 2012.

```
-- The date parameter
declare @Date datetime
set @Date = '2012-04-11'

declare @FromDate datetime
declare @ToDate datetime

-- set FromFate to first of april
set @FromDate = dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @Date), 0)
-- set ToDate to first of may
set @ToDate = dateadd(month, 1+datediff(month, 0, @Date), 0)

select *
from YourTable
where [Date] >= @FromDate and [Date] < @ToDate
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show data for a particular year and month you can use the [YEAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx) and [MONTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx) functions:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE YEAR(mydate) = 2012 AND MONTH(mydate) = 3 -- March, 2012
```

Comment: thanks Jakob and Arion, in ur query u r manually giving the value of date and month as 2012 and 3, I need to get it automatically from my query.....for example YEAR(mydate)=DATENAME(MONTH,@DATE)....here consider the @DATE as '2012-04-11', here its returns the output as APRIL as month and cannot convert string to int.....is it possible to get the month in number like "4"

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems that your field `Date` is not of type `varchar` or `nvarchar`, so using a condition where a Datetime = string is obviously wrong.

Have you tried

```
WHERE DATE= @Date
```

Comment: s its a Datetime type.......as u said If I use WHERE DATE=@Date and am passing the value of @Date is '2012-04-11' it should display the records of 11th April of 2012 only, right....I need to display all the datas on April month if I pass the Date value as '2012-04-11'.....any idea

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be:

```
DATENAME(MONTH, @Date)
```

Instead of:

```
DATANAME(MONTH,'@Date')
```

(Notice "DATA" vs "DATE" and @Date isn't in quotations)

Then to use this against a date/datetime column you would have to cast both sides like below:

```
WHERE datename(Month, [Date]) = datename(Month, [Date])
```

Warning: The above does not use any indexes so isn't as efficient as `"WHERE Date = Date"`

Answer (score 1):

First: Remove '' from variable. @Date, not '@Date'

If you want to find dates from specific month. (You have to remember about year condition also)

```
WHERE DATANAME(MONTH, @Date) = 'April'
```

if you want to find exact date:

```
WHERE DATE = @date
```

Comment: in ur query u r manually giving the month value as 'April', but my requirement is it has to be assigned automatically, If I give the date as '2012-04-11' it should automatically get the month as 04 or April and display all the datas on April

Comment: So maybe something like this WHERE DATANAME(MONTH, @Date) = DATENAME(MONTH, DATE)